# A question about some polynomial

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Then 
$$ p_n = 1+\prod_{i=1}^r{p_{k_i}^{a_i}} $$ 
with $k_i < n$, $1 \le i \le r$ since this is just the prime factorization of $p_n-1$. Consider the polynomial:
$$f_n = 1+\prod_{i=1}^r{X_{k_i}^{a_i}} $$ 
Computing this polynomial for small values of $n$ it seems that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there any reason for this, or might this polynomial be also reducible?

Comment: $5=1+2^2$, so $f_3=1+X_1^2$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$. Are you asking about irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$, or maybe over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: By Gauss's Lemma, irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ here is equivalent to irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$; it's not necessarily the case that non-trivial factorizations of $f_n$ correspond to non-trivial factorizations of $p_n$, but they 'should' often enough that there's a very strong bias towards irreducibility here.

Comment: Could perhaps reduce the problem to showing irreducibility of univariate $f(x)=p_{k_2}\dots p_{k_r} x^{a_{k_1}}+1$, which seems to be indeed irreducible as well.